# Update user using DirectoryService

Tags: directoryservices

So I managed to get some code rolling for updating the AD from an external sourced. However, I'm a bit confused about how it works.
I have a person with sAMAccount xxxx existing in different OUs.
Now, I only want to update the info in a specific OU, so I put that in my LDAP path. Still, it seem that the info has been updated in different OU's as well?

Could that be possible? Is it because there's only one "Person" object, or do the "GetDirectoryEntry()" not put me where I thought in the tree? Or.. am I only imagine and the weird things I see is becausde of something else.

Some code

```
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP://my.path/ou=myou, dc=my, dc=path);
            entry.Username = myUser
            entry.Password = myPass
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            searcher.Filter = @"(&(objectClass=Person)(SamAccountname=" + person.id + "))";
            SearchResult result = searcher.FindOne();

                    try
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                        user.Properties["displayName"].Value = person.DisplayName;
                        user.Properties["givenName"].Value = person.Firstname;
                        user.CommitChanges();
                        user.Close();
                    }
                    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
```

EDIT: It did update the Person object in all the OU's. So either the Person object is one and the same in the whole AD, whick makes my attempt to update them in only the specific OU pointless, or does the "result.GetDirectoryEntry" ignore the fact that I thought I was working only in my specific OU declared in my LDAP path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality confirmed, still wonder why I needed a specific test-ou since it's still the same users. Anyway, here we go!